# Session factory not knowing annotated entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-annotations, hibernate-annotations

I have some problem when inherit session factory and configuration from another project : 
I have two separate project (core-project, the projects uses core as library) 
configuration of my core-project is the following code :

```
    package ir.badnava.pressmining.core.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.base.BaseRawEntity;
import ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.page.RawPageEntity;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ir.badnava.pressmining" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:database.properties" })
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        setAnotatedClasses(sessionFactory);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    protected void setAnotatedClasses(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory) {
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class<?>[]{BaseRawEntity.class, RawPageEntity.class});
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

and the child project configuration is the following code :

```
package com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.crawler.WebCrawler;
import com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.models.speciallist.RepositoryList;
import com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.models.speciallist.RepositoryListManager;
import com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.models.urlrepo.UrlRepository;
import com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.models.urlrepo.UrlRepositoryManager;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends ir.badnava.pressmining.core.config.AppConfig{

    @Bean
    public RepositoryListManager getRepositoryListManager() {
        return new RepositoryListManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlRepositoryManager getUrlRepositoryManager() {
        return new UrlRepositoryManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebCrawler getWebCrawler(){
        return new WebCrawler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setAnotatedClasses(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory) {
        super.setAnotatedClasses(sessionFactory);
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class<?>[]{RepositoryList.class, UrlRepository.class});
    }

}
```

and my problem is that in the child project I overload the setAnnotatedClass method and calling it's super and give the session factory my entities class but after doing something like save or update session factory says that unknown mapping entity

I have no idea about what did I wrong in these code because I did that before with XML file configuration

**Update :**
log :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.page.RawPageEntity
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.base.BaseDao.save(BaseDao.java:16)
    at ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.base.BaseDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d95ff2ca.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.base.BaseDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95dae3fd.save(<generated>)
    at ir.badnava.pressmining.core.models.raw.base.BaseManager.save(BaseManager.java:23)
    at com.badnava.pressmining.web.crawler.crawler.WebCrawler$3.run(WebCrawler.java:142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It is a setter method (should be) and if so, it will replace the value when you invoke it in the 2nd time.

Comment: I even test that by getting the class list from super and set them in the child class but no thing changed

Comment: I also debug that and after calling the setAnnotatedClasses() sessionfactory have all of the 4 class but when want to save some object from core project I get the exception

Comment: @sura2k you were right that's fix the problem but I don't know why last night I didn't get result by doing some thing like these. so many thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved : 
the problem was that the setAnnotatedClasses method is a setter method and I changed my code to bellow code and that's work

```
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] setAnotatedClasses() {
        Class<?>[] superClasses = super.setAnotatedClasses(sessionFactory);
        Class<?>[] childClasses = new Class<?>[]{RepositoryList.class, UrlRepository.class};
        Class<?>[] allClasses = new Class<?>[childClasses.length + superClasses.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < allClasses.length; i++) {
            if (i < superClasses.length)
                allClasses[i] = superClasses[i];
            else
                allClasses[i] = childClasses[i-childClasses.length];
        }
        return allClasses;
    }
```

thanks to @sura2k

Comment: To khafan, to khub:D